# multiplication of square root function

Tags: functions

I have a function :

> `f(x) = 3√(2x + 5) - 4`

I have to resolve

> f = g x h
>
> g(x) = 3 h(x) = ?

The answer is

> h(x) = √(2x-5) - 4/3

However, I don't know what to do to get this answer.

I know I have to devide 3 by 3 and -4 by 3, but I don't know why 5 become -5.

Edit: 
I have

> f(x) = 3√(2x + 5) - 4
>
> g(x) = 3
>
> h(x) = ?

I have to find h(x) if `f(x) = g(x) x h(x)`. The answer in my book is

> h(x) = √(2x-5) - 4/3

I don't know how to get this, especially -5.

Basically, `3 X (√(2x-5) - 4/3) = 3√(2x + 5) - 4`

Is there an error in my book?

Comment: Is this $$3\sqrt{2x+5}-4=3h(x)$$?

Answer (score 0):

If so, then we get $$h(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{2x+5}-4}{3}=\frac{3\sqrt{2x+5}}{3}-\frac{4}{3}=…$$

Comment: I probably poorly explained the situation.

I have f(x) = 3√(2x + 5) - 4
g(x) = 3 
h(x) = ?
I have to find h(x).

The answer in my book is h(x) = √(2x-5) - 4/3.
I don't know how to get this, especially -5.